# Trying to create a flag based on ranking values in two separate columns

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query where I have duplicate rows for certain ID's, but have two different columns created by window functions and need to create a flag for each row based on a certain order.  I've provided an example below of what the data looks like.

I have a RANK_ONE column that returns a ranked value or null and not every ID has a value, but if it has a one, I need it to return a 1 for the row that contains 1.

The RANK_TWO column is basically the same, but I need to flag the 1 row IF there isn't already a 1 flagged from RANK_ONE for the same ID.

[image]

The PRIMARY column is my desired outcome.  Any thoughts?

I don't know if I've just been in the query too long and can't see a simple solution right in front of me, but it's driving me nuts trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `rank_one` if it is every 1 for the `id` and otherwise `rank_two`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when max(case when rank_one = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) = 1 and rank_one = 1 then 1
             when max(case when rank_one = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) = 1 then 0
             when rank_two = 1 then 1
             else 0
        end) as primary
from t;
```

Comment: It's not evaluating the portion where rank_two = 1 then 1 if there is nothing but null values in rank_one for that ID and there aren't duplicates of that ID.  Not a huge deal though since I can just use another case statement in the final select to assign 1 for null values.  It could also be how I implemented the solution, but this works.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @RobertFingerhut . . . I fixed the answer.  I was thinking that `rank_one` only took on `NULL` or `1` -- apparently just ignoring the data in your question.  The intention is to determine if `rank_one = 1` is in the group for the first two `when` clauses.

Comment: It was my bonehead implementation of the solution.  I created a separate CTE just to perform this function and it broke down when I joined it back in.  I tried to edit my previous comment but I had left too much time pass.